# Helm chart Rendering errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am running into below error while applying helm chart version 2.
Any help would be appreciated?

Please see yaml file.

Error: render error in "prometheus/templates/prometheus-adapter/custom-metrics-apiserver-deployment.yaml": template: prometheus/templates/prometheus-adapter/custom-metrics-apiserver-deployment.yaml:29:29: executing "prometheus/templates/prometheus-adapter/custom-metrics-apiserver-deployment.yaml" at <include (print $.Template.BasePath "/custom-metrics-configmap.yaml") .>: error calling include: template: no template "prometheus/templates/custom-metrics-configmap.yaml" associated with template "gotpl"

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ template "k8s-prometheus-adapter.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "k8s-prometheus-adapter.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
  name: {{ template "k8s-prometheus-adapter.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.adapter.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "k8s-prometheus-adapter.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "k8s-prometheus-adapter.name" . }}
        chart: {{ template "k8s-prometheus-adapter.chart" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
        heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
        {{- with .Values.adapter.podLabels }}
        {{- toYaml . | trim | nindent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
      name: {{ template "k8s-prometheus-adapter.name" . }}
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/custom-metrics-configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
        {{- with .Values.adapter.podAnnotations }}
        {{- toYaml . | trim | nindent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ template "k8s-prometheus-adapter.serviceAccountName" . }}
      {{- if .Values.adapter.hostNetwork.enabled }}
      hostNetwork: true
      {{- end }}
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.adapter.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.adapter.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.adapter.image.pullPolicy }}
        args:
        - /adapter
        - --secure-port={{ .Values.adapter.listenPort }}
        {{- if .Values.adapter.tls.enable }}
- --tls-cert-file=/var/run/serving-cert/tls.crt
        - --tls-private-key-file=/var/run/serving-cert/tls.key
        {{- end }}
        - --cert-dir=/tmp/cert
        - --logtostderr=true
        - --prometheus-url={{ .Values.adapter.prometheus.url }}{{ if .Values.adapter.prometheus.port }}:{{ .Values.adapter.prometheus.port }}{{end}}{{ .Values.adapter.prometheus.path }}
        - --metrics-relist-interval={{ .Values.adapter.metricsRelistInterval }}
        - --v={{ .Values.adapter.logLevel }}
        - --config=/etc/adapter/config.yaml
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.adapter.listenPort }}
          name: https
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
        {{- if .Values.adapter.resources }}
        resources:
          {{- toYaml .Values.adapter.resources | nindent 10 }}
        {{- end }}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop: ["all"]
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 10001
        volumeMounts:
        {{- if .Values.adapter.extraVolumeMounts }}
        {{ toYaml .Values.adapter.extraVolumeMounts | trim | nindent 8 }}
        {{ end }}
        - mountPath: /etc/adapter/
          name: config
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp
{{- if .Values.adapter.tls.enable }}
        - mountPath: /var/run/serving-cert
          name: volume-serving-cert
          readOnly: true
        {{- end }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml .Values.adapter.nodeSelector | nindent 8 }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml .Values.adapter.affinity | nindent 8 }}
      priorityClassName: {{ .Values.adapter.priorityClassName }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml .Values.adapter.tolerations | nindent 8 }}
      {{- if .Values.adapter.image.pullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- range .Values.adapter.image.pullSecrets }}
        - name: {{ . }}
        {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
      volumes:
      {{- if .Values.adapter.extraVolumes  }}
      {{ toYaml .Values.adapter.extraVolumes | trim | nindent 6 }}
      {{ end }}
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: {{ .Values.adapter.rules.existing | default (include "k8s-prometheus-adapter.fullname" . ) }}
      - name: tmp
        emptyDir: {}
      {{- if .Values.adapter.tls.enable }}
      - name: volume-serving-cert
        secret:
          secretName: {{ template "k8s-prometheus-adapter.fullname" . }}
      {{- end }}
```

Comment: Please share your yaml configs by editing your question.

Comment: i see you are using `include` , which actually uses the template file, do you have anything like `.tpl` file in your chart dir?

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty Yes there is a .tpl file in chart directory.

Comment: Its clearly saying that the file `prometheus/templates/custom-metrics-configmap.yaml` is not present, can you verify that probably? because its checking the checksum at `spec.template.annotations.checksum/config`, if you do not want that for some reason, you can comment/remove  that particular line in annotations.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty I am not clear why it is looking for custom-metrics-configmap.yaml under prometheus dir.That fils is actually under templates/prometheus-adapter directory.Is this driven by .tpl?

Comment: Because the deployment as well looks like it's for the Prometheus adapter. you can see the other keys and values. could you also provide the chart source if its opensource?